# Tiny MCE v6 loading issue

Tags: tinymce

I'm using the open-source version and have download the latest zip file containing all the server side code. However, when I run the page I get the following errors on the javascript console. All of the errors are from the tiny mce site. I put in the url in a separate web page and got a "can't find the page error". Doesn't anyone know why this is occurring and is there a work around.

[This is the javascript console for the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkXLm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE 6 has some changes you will need to address.  There is a migration guide in the documentation that outlines what you may need to change:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/migration-from-5x/